# How do I Tell What my Java Program is Doing?

Tags: java, debugging, jar, compilation, speech-to-text

I have my first little Java program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;

public class Sphinx {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("models/en-us/en-us");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath("models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter("status.txt"));
        LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
        recognizer.startRecognition(true);
        pw.print("running");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
        recognizer.stopRecognition();
        pw.print("stopped");
        pw.close();

        PrintWriter pw2 = new PrintWriter(new PrintWriter("result.txt"));
        pw2.println(result);
        pw2.close();
    }
}
```

And as you can tell, it is an executable that manages a speech to text engine, created by CMU.

It outputs it's status, and speech to text results into two different text files.

Now, the annoying thing is, I have absolutely no clue as to whether or not my program is even doing anything or not. I double-click on the .jar, say something into my microphone, but none of the text files are changing, or doing anything at all.

I ran the program through the compiler, and it's saying everything is fine. But it's clearly not, and I have no way of telling where the problem is.

So, I need to know methods to tell what is going on inside my Java program, and where the errors are occurring.

***EDIT:***

I should probably let people who are coming to the question know what's going on. I never did get a answer that actually worked, but I recently learned that the speech-to-text engine I was using was broken anyways, so it didn't really matter. I have since then moved on to a new engine: PyAudio.

Comment: Sprinkle `System.out.println`s everywhere or use a debugger. "print debugging" is great for simple stuff. Have it print out different variable values and see what's going on. [Obligatory reading suggestion](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Carcigenicate Okay, but where would those system out's come from? The CMD?

Comment: Yes. Or you could log to the disk if need be. The console is usually sufficient unless you're dealing with large amounts of information over an long time period.

Answer (score 2):

The PrintWriter class is **buffered** by default. It will only really write to the file when there is enough data in the buffer, to reduce operating-system overhead. That's why you don't see anything in the file - the data is kept into memory until the buffer is full.

If you want data to end up in the file immediately, you can either call the `flush` method on the PrintWriter when you want to write to the file; or when you construct it, you can pass `true` as the second argument to make it *auto-flushing*. That way, it will flush after every print.

However there is no constructor that takes a String and the autoFlush flag, so you need to write:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("status.txt"), true);
```

(Note that there is no point in wrapping a PrintWriter inside a PrintWriter like you do in your original code).